# Docker and Drupal 8 - settings.php

Tags: drupal, docker, systemd

I'm trying to dockerize Drupal 8, and I'm running into this issue that after running Drupal 8 in a container and installing it, if I then remove the container and start it again, it prompts to install it again.

The thing is, when Drupal is installed, a `settings.php` file is created with the database details.

I wanted to create a systemd unit file for launching the Drupal 8 container in a smart way that even if it's removed, it should start again next time with the same installation.

Someone recommended me to write a systemd unit file with `ConditionPathExists=` to mount `settings.php` based on whether it's there locally, however I think this is not going to fully work, because on installation in the container, the generated `settings.php` file wouldn't be persisted back to the host machine.

So how can I solve the issue of making a Docker container for Drupal that offers to install if it hasn't been installed yet, and from then on use the installed instance even if the container is removed and rebuilt?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using the official docker image for drupal

- https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/

Saves a lot of time and if you still need to customize your environment at least you can look at its Dockerfile and see how it's been done by the community.

### Container persistence

When a container is stopped it can be restarted. All it's files are preserved including any settings.php files that may have been created.

A brand new container, on the other hand, will always start from scratch no simple way to avoid this. To persist data across container instances you need to use volumes.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Here's how it's done:

```
#
# Create a data container
#
docker create \
  -v /var/www/html/sites \
  -v /var/www/private \
  --name my-data \
  drupal

#
# Run drupal without a db container (select sqlite on first install)
#
docker run --volumes-from my-data --name my-drupal -p 8080:80 -d drupal
```

Note:

- You could use volume mappings to the host machine, but this data container pattern is more flexible, for example when upgrading drupal.

### How it works

Drupal 8 is built on top of the offical PHP language image.

- [Drupal 8.1 Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/blob/4fe7a837c7de5ea753070be21e64f0cb971493a7/8.1/apache/Dockerfile)
- [Php 7 Apache Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/8943e1e6a930768994fbc29f4df89d0a3fd65e12/7.0/apache/Dockerfile)

In the PHP buildfile note how Apache is being run in the [foreground](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/8943e1e6a930768994fbc29f4df89d0a3fd65e12/7.0/apache/Dockerfile#L83)?

```
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

No need for systemd running inside the container.

Comment: This does seem to go against the general suggested systemd unit file pattern I see everywhere that you create the container and remove it when stopping it, to make room for upgrading the container; with your example, I'm not sure how I could upgrade. Also I'm worried about the fact that the folder that would contain `settings.php` also contains other versioned files; so I think I couldn't just mount a host volume that doesn't even exist yet, because that important folder would appear completely empty in the container, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi In the above pattern the container data is kept in the container called "my-data". Upgrade is easy, kill the container called "my-drupal", perform a new docker pull (to get the latest drupal image) then launch a new container. As for the folder containing versioned files that's hard to avoid and is specific to how Drupal manages its file really. That's why the problem is mitigated by saving content in the "sites" directory.

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi Running systemd within the container will not manage the container instances, it's the docker daemon that does that. It should be noted that using systemd as a replacement for the Docker daemon is a controversial subject but not something users currently have any control over. For a glimpse of one possible Docker future, see: https://containerd.tools/

Comment: The systemd stuff is running in the host, I know. But anyway, with your examples there would be no way to install Drupal initially, because I'd be mapping empty directories to directories in Drupal that contain important files for installation (e.g. the base settings file that it uses to create settings.php)

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi Have you tried my example? After running the standard install install the settings file is generated in the sites directory which is one of the persisted volumes: "/var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php"

Comment: I'll try, but I don't think this is going to work. I already tried mounting volumes with -v, and the result was the installer couldn't install, because since I replaced the original sites/ folder with an empty one with my mount, and thus important files for installation were missing.